# Repeating code pattern

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I have certain code pattern (which log performance and other variable for each function) which need to be present in every function, and I do not want to repeat the code over and over again. Here is what the code looks like:

```
public OutClass FUNC-X
{
 if (IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        Logger("Start DataLibrary: FUNC-X");
    }
try
{
    CheckInitSucceeded();

    GetAuthenticationTokens();

    var dm = new Manager();

    /**
    * THIS SINGLE LINE IS THE VARIABLE PART
    **/
    var output = dm.FUNC-X(...);

    if (IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        var data = Serialize(output);
        Logger(output);
    }
    return output;
}
catch (WebFaultException)
{
    throw;
}
catch (OtherException ex)
{
    if (Logger.IsErrorEnabled)
    {
        Logger.LogError("Exception in FUNC-X", ex);
    }
    throw new OtherException("Some Message");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (IsErrorEnabled)
    {
        Logger("Exception in FUNC-X", ex);
    }

    throw new Exception("Generic Exception");
}
finally
{
    if (IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        Logger("End FUNC-X");
    }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I just need to replace FUNC-X with FUNC-Y or FUNC-Z everywhere this name occurs, is there some kind of design pattern which I can follow?

I'm sorry if the question is vague, I shall be happy to provide any details you ask.

Comment: Looks to me like you're just after some sort of Factory pattern.. but without a better example its hard to tell..

Comment: So what I want is that whenever I create a new function instead of copying and pasting the code I should be able to tell the name of the function and it automatically does the part of replacing `Func-X` with `Func-Y`.

Comment: Is the result always the OutClass class? Or that class depends on the function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there are many ways to provide nice log code.

1. Use [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). There is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging) and [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/). You can use [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) library. All of them after config supports writing of method name.
2. You can use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) and generate code for all funcs before compile.
3. You can write one global logging method that accepts `Func<object> method` and `string methodName`. Suppose you named your logging method `LogAndExecute`. Then to call you must write smth like:

   ```
   LogAndExecute("func-x", () => dm.Func-X(/*your args*/))
   ```

   If you got problems with different different return types of your funcs, use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple delegate to accept the variable part as parameter (if no. of parameters to function call in single line are same)

```
    public void Function_X(Func<object,..> func)
    {
        if (IsDebugEnabled)
        {
                Logger("Start DataLibrary: FUNC-X");
        }
        try
        {
            CheckInitSucceeded();

            GetAuthenticationTokens();

            var dm = new Manager();

            /**
            * THIS SINGLE LINE IS THE VARIABLE PART
            **/
        //    var output = dm.FUNC-X(...);
            var output = func(...);

            if (IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                var data = Serialize(output);
                Logger(output);
            }
            return output;
        }
        catch (WebFaultException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (OtherException ex)
        {
            if (Logger.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Exception in FUNC-X", ex);
            }
            throw new OtherException("Some Message");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                Logger("Exception in FUNC-X", ex);
            }

            throw new Exception("Generic Exception");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                Logger("End FUNC-X");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure how delegates will take care of this, I want to replace `Func-X` with `Func-Y` in not only the string part but also the call to the external function `dm.Func-X`

Comment: Pass `Manager` as argument to delegate. And call like, `func(dm, <other parameters>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common function that accepts a Func delegate:

```
    static public TOutClass CommonFunc<TOutClass>(Func<Manager, TOutClass> func)
    {
        if (IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            Logger("Start DataLibrary: FUNC-X");
        }
        try
        {
            CheckInitSucceeded();

            GetAuthenticationTokens();

            var dm = new Manager();
            TOutClass output = func(dm);

            if (IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                var data = Serialize(output);
                Logger(output);
            }
            return output;
        }
        catch
            [...]
    }
```

Your would write your functions as:

```
public OutClass FUNC-X(...)
{

   return CommonFunc(dm=>dm.FUNC-X(...));
}
```